# How to start an Activity from the running service ( like the input method ) in the "Running services" page

Tags: android, service, android-activity

as you can find in the "Running services" page,
like the softkeyboard, "input method: touch to manage", can start a custom Activity。
my service is not a input method or wallpaper or so， how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do it from the Running Services page.

The only way to start a service is through an intent, which your Service must be listening to, as declared in your manifest. Please consult the documentation.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer!  But, do you misunderstand my question? "The only way to start a service is through an intent"? My service IS running, and I just what to add an "Setting" Activity,so that I can "touch to manage" and start it in the "Running services" page;